# Setting default order for all the tables in a database using lumen

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

I have a complete application which is written using lumen. The application is complete. I just need to add order by clause with each query in the application which is somehow time taking to add. After searching everywhere I found the following method.

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) {
    $builder->orderBy('date', 'desc');
   });
}
```

I shall have to add above function in each model. This is also a reasonable solution but I do not want to do this. I want to add this function on a single place rather than adding in each model like in any service provider or somewhere else.I am not much familure with this framework. Please, help if any one knows about its solution. Please, note that the timestamp field names for order by has different prefix. Eg. tbl_created_at is the Created_at field in a table named column and prnt_created_at field is Created_at field in a table named prints. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a `trait`, in the trait you can still use the methods and variables from class that is using the trait:

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

trait DefaultOrderByDate
{
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        $field = parent::CREATED_AT;

        static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) use ($field) {
            $builder->orderBy($field, 'desc');
        });
    }
}
```

Now in your models you can use them like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\DefaultOrderByDate;

class SomeModel extends Model
{
   use DefaultOrderByDate;

    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'prnt_created_at';

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'prnt_updated_at';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you did not read full question. The field names "Created_at" will be different for each table which is defined in model. Created_at="tbl_created_at"

Comment: Sorry, corrected my answer again... `parent` is the class including the trait, not tested, but this should get you started, I hope.

Comment: Can you share a example model with the changed timestamp? Can you share any errors you're getting?

Comment: Thank you so much this code worked for me after fixing some issues.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a error free solution to this question.

1: Create a Trait at first step

```
   <?php
     namespace App\Traits;
     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
     trait DefaultOrderByDate
     {
        protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        $field = self::CREATED_AT;

         static::addGlobalScope('order', function (Builder $builder) use ($field) {
            $builder->orderBy($field, 'desc');
         });
       }
    }
```

2: Create a model after creating trait

```
<?PHP
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\DefaultOrderByDate;

class SomeModel extends Model
{
  use DefaultOrderByDate;

  /**
   * The name of the "created at" column.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  const CREATED_AT = 'prnt_created_at';

  /**
   * The name of the "updated at" column.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   const UPDATED_AT = 'prnt_updated_at';
}
```